# Testing events in Solidity contracts using Truffle

Tags: javascript, testing, solidity, truffle

I am trying to test if an event occurs but the test passes no matter what the input is.

I guess I am doing somthing wrong waiting for a result and that it just through the test and thus is never asserted to false.

My test looks like this (acc2 is a const holding an address):

```
it('Should emit an event on this call.', async () => {
    const testingOraclize = await TestingOraclize.new()
    let actual = await testingOraclize.myFunc({from:acc2})
    await truffleAssert.eventEmitted(actual , 'ParticipateStatus', async (res) => {
      return res._statusCode.toNumber() === 0;
    })
  });
```

My imports in the testing file are:

```
const TestingOraclize = artifacts.require('contracts/BetBank.sol');
const assert = require("chai").assert;
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
```

The event in the Solidity contract

```
event ParticipateStatus(uint8 _statusCode, address _owner, address _participant);
```

MyFunc (addresses[msg.sender] does resolve to true):

```
function MyFunc() external payable {
    if (addresses[msg.sender]) {
      emit ParticipateStatus(0, allRunningBets[_betListIndex].betPlacer, msg.sender);
      return;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add await for the below line as well as its actually a promise that needs to be resolved. Since, you are not waiting here for the promise to be fulfilled, looks like the control is jumping to the next line which happens to be your event triggered.

```
let actual = await testingOraclize.myFunc({from:acc2})
```

**Edit 1:**

Remove the async and await in the truffleAssert function.

Comment: I was about to hit my head on the table top but that was not it. Something went wrong posting the question. There actually is an await there in the code. So that's not the issue.

Comment: Share the code of the function myFunc something could be missing there as there’s nothing else to tell just looking at the Test case

Comment: I edited the original post. There are actually multiple if statements in there but to make it more readable I left those out as this first one is the branch I am interested in and has the issue.

Comment: Ah so you are expecting if the input that is the amount of ether that you are sending should be greater than zero and only then that function should be executed? If that’s the case then you need to understand making payable only allows the function to accept ether which his optimal. Meaning it’s not mandatory for user to send ether. That logic you should handle in the function like require(msg.value > 0 ether);

Comment: No, I am expecting it to emit the event as the ondition resolves to true (the msg.sender maps to true). I tried re-writing the test by using an assert.equals(), catching the result of the truffleAssert in a bool and I can see the event is emitted but is not caught in the test. It looks like it just falls through the test never doing the truffleAssert().

Comment: Can you remove the await before the truffleAssert and try it. Don’t see the requirement of having await in the truffleAssert documentation.

Comment: And even the callback function inside the truffleAssert function if you can try removing the async

Comment: I ran a few tests and all seems to do as expected. In other words, you solved it! I am starting to believe that a lot of tutorials I find online contain code that was not tested by the authors. This is not the first time I tried using a pieve of code I found as I stencil, just to discover that I need to remove parts of it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That’s great to hear. I have edited my answer with the last comment so that someone visiting this answer in the future will find useful. Yeah, a lot of tutorials out there aren’t tested, it’s best to go with the documentation if one has it.

Comment: Hi @RuudHermans, I'm the author of the truffle-assertions library that you're using. Thanks for using the library, and happy to see that you've resolved the issue. Do you have links to the tutorials you used, so I can see what's wrong with them? In any case, there's documentation on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions), and I wrote a [tutorial on my own blog as well](https://kalis.me/check-events-solidity-smart-contract-test-truffle/)

Comment: @RoscoKalis I don't have that link no more. It was not part of any official documentation, if I remember it correctly it was from an article on medium.com